# Flutter : Could not find the correct Provider

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-provider

I am tying to implement `Firebase Authentication` in my `flutter` app, with the help of `provider`. First, I am checking whether the user is already signed in, if yes, i AM sending him to the **home** screen. Else I am sending him to the **Login** screen.

Please check my code below.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
            child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Customer App',

                home: AuthWrapper(), 
                routes: {
                    '/account': (context) => AccountPage(),
                },
            ), create: (BuildContext context) {
                AuthService();
            },
        );
    }
}
```

**auth.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthService with ChangeNotifier{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser _user=null;

//Sign in with username and password
  Future signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user;

    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
          user = result.user;

      if (user != null) {
        print("Sign in success: " + user.email);
        _user = user;
      } else {
        print("sign in failed");
        _user = null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    finally{
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

//Get the current user
  FirebaseUser getCurrentUser()  {
    return _user;
  }

}
```

**auth_wrapper.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:customer/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:customer/pages/login.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthWrapper() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var currentUser =Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
      return LoginPage();
    } else {
      return HomePage();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this app, i get the following error.

```
I/flutter ( 3364): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building AuthWrapper(dirty):
I/flutter ( 3364): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthService> above this AuthWrapper Widget
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): To fix, please:
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Ensure the Provider<AuthService> is an ancestor to this AuthWrapper Widget
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Provide types to Provider<AuthService>
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Provide types to Consumer<AuthService>
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Provide types to Provider.of<AuthService>()
I/flutter ( 3364):   * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
I/flutter ( 3364): https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): The relevant error-causing widget was:
[38;5;248mI/flutter ( 3364):   AuthWrapper[39;49m
I/flutter ( 3364):
I/flutter ( 3364): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[38;5;248mI/flutter ( 3364): #0      Provider.of[39;49m
[38;5;248mI/flutter ( 3364): #1      AuthWrapper.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #2      StatelessElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #4      Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #6      ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #7      Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #8      Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter ( 3364): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[3
```

I am newly trying out the `provider` patter, whats really going on here?

I also has a second question. Well, `provider` is a pattern. But in flutter we know things get little out of context so, does that mean all business logic (REST API Related) need to take place in `provider` ? Or else, only use in places where you need the `observer` pattern behaviour?

Comment: In the create argument you are not returning AuthService(); . Either use the fat arrow function or just add a return before AuthService();

Answer (score 0):

I think value provider could be best solution for your case. Following minimal code help you to understand more.

I think it is totally dependent on you, if you think data is not that much big then you can avoid using provider because it create lot’s of other boilerplate code. However i also suggest you to use flutter_bloc package.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: FireBaseWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FireBaseWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(_user);
    if (_user != null)
      return FireBase();
    else
      return Register();
  }
}

    class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User firebaseUserToUser(FirebaseUser _user) {
    return _user != null ? User(userId: _user.uid) : null;
  }

  //stream of User
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(firebaseUserToUser);
  }

  // firebase sign in Anonymously
  Future signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      AuthResult _authResult = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser _user = _authResult.user;
      return firebaseUserToUser(_user);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signInWithIdPassword({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      AuthResult _authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser _user = _authResult.user;
      return firebaseUserToUser(_user);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signUpWithIdPassword({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      AuthResult _authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email.trim(), password: password);
      FirebaseUser _user = _authResult.user;
      return firebaseUserToUser(_user);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```